# How do i get the width and height after using appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, i have a parent div named `'wrapper'` and I am adding other div's: `divImg`, counter and caption. Then I am centering the `'wrapper'`.

Appending the divs to 'wrapper' works ok. I'm stuck on how to center the `'wrapper'`. For some reason, I cannot get the width and height of the 'wrapper' after using `appendTo`. It's always the same with and height.

How do I get the width and height after using `appendTo`, see my code below:

```
function appendImage() {
var wrapperWidth;
var wrapperHeight;
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();

var wrapper = $("#modal-wrapper");

var divImg = $("<div></div>")
    .hide()
    .attr("id", "container-img")
    .appendTo(wrapper);

var counter = $("<p></p>")
    .hide()
    .addClass("slideshowCounter")
    .text(text goes here...)
    .appendTo(wrapper);

var caption = $("<p></p>")
    .hide()
    .addClass("imgCaption")
    .text(caption goes here...)
    .appendTo(wrapper);

// preload the image
var img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = function() {
        // set the image width / height
        $(this).width(this.width).height(this.height).appendTo(divImg);

        wrapperWidth = wrapper.outerWidth();

        // ERROR, always the same width
        alert(wrapperWidth);

        wrapperHeight = wrapper.outerHeight();

        wrapper.css({
            width: wrapperWidth,
            height: wrapperHeight,
            left: ((windowWidth - wrapperWidth) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft()),
            top: ((windowHeight - wrapperWidth) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop())
        }).show( "slow", function() {
            // fadein the image and other
            divImg.fadeIn(800);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: just use [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) or [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Comment: @vladkras are you serious?

Comment: @Marco hidden elements does show width and height 0.

Comment: @Marco seriously, 1. loading image is not the same thing as rendering it in browser, js is not supposed to work with dimensions and other properties of elements until you see them page (aka invisible) 2. your code should be 2-3 times shorter, can you put 2 `<p></p>` in wrapper just in html, not using js? 3. You can look through the code of that libraries for good ideas and coding style

Comment: @vladkras: got it! your solution is to use fancybox or lightbox...